# Identifying group of units of monoid to a point

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, monoid, congruence-relations

Let $S$ be a monoid. Let $\mathfrak{g}(S)$ be the group of units of $S$, and denote by $S/A$ the quotient $S/\sim_A$ where $\sim_A$ is the smallest congruence such that $a\sim_A a'$ for all $a, a'\in A$. Call $\mathfrak{a}(S) = S/\mathfrak{g}(S)$ the absolution of $S$. Call a monoid $S$ absolute if $\mathfrak{g}(S) = \{1\}$ or equivalently $\mathfrak{a}(S) = S$.

> Is the absolution $\mathfrak{a}(S)$ of a monoid $S$ an absolute monoid?

---

This is true for monoids of size $\leq 4$ (checked by me).

Its also true if $S$ is commutative since the congruence $\sim\ =\ \sim_{\mathfrak{g}(S)}$ is then $x\sim y$ iff $x = uy$ for some unit $u$.

@Thorgott observed the following:

In general, $\sim$ is the transitive closure of the relation $\sim'$ such that $x\sim' y$ iff there exist $z_1, ..., z_n\in S$ and $a_1, ..., a_n, a_1', ..., a_n'\in \mathfrak{g}(S)$ such that $a_1z_1\cdots a_nz_n = a_1'z_1\cdots a_n'z_n$.

If $\mathfrak{g}(S)$ coincides with the set of left (or right) units of $S$, then one then easily shows from above characterization of $\sim$ that $x\sim' y$ and $x\in \mathfrak{g}(S)$ implies $y\in \mathfrak{g}(S)$. This means $\mathfrak{g}(S)$ is an equivalence class of $\sim$, so $\mathfrak{a}(S)$ is an absolute monoid.

Comment: More generally, this should hold as long as $\mathfrak{g}(S)$ coincides with the set of elements having a left- or right-inverse.

Comment: The idea behind the name absolute monoid is that for example, the absolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ with multiplication is $\mathbb{N}_0$. The idea is that absolution removes the dependence on the "sign".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the functions $a,b,u:\mathbb{N}^2\to\mathbb{N}^2$ defined by $a(m,n)=(m+1,n)$, $b(m,n)=(\max(m-1,0),n)$, and $u(m,n)=(n,m)$.  Let $S$ be the monoid of functions $\mathbb{N}^2\to\mathbb{N}^2$ generated by $a,b,$ and $u$.  Explicitly, $S$ is the set of all functions that can be constructed by repeatedly right-shifting or left-shifting on each coordinate separately, and then optionally swapping the coordinates.  The only units of $S$ are $1$ and $u$.

Now note that $ba=1$ and $a$ commutes with $ubu$.  So in the absolution $\mathfrak{a}(S)$, $a$ and $b$ will commute and thus be units.  Note also that there is a homomorphism $f:S\to\mathbb{Z}$ which sends a function to the sum of the total net shifts that it does on each coordinate, so $f(a)=1$, $f(b)=-1$, and $f(u)=0$.  Since $f(u)=0$ this induces a homomorphism $\mathfrak{a}(S)\to\mathbb{Z}$ that sends $a$ to $1$ and $b$ to $-1$, so $a,b\neq 1$ in $\mathfrak{a}(S)$.  Thus $\mathfrak{a}(S)$ is not absolute.  (In fact, this homomorphism $\mathfrak{a}(S)\to\mathbb{Z}$ is an isomorphism.)

Comment: I would guess that in general, you have to iterate $\mathfrak{a}$ infinitely many times in order to get an absolute monoid.

Comment: This is also an example that existence of retraction $g:S\to \mathfrak{g}(S)$ and $\mathfrak{a}(S)$ being free doesn't imply that $S$ is a direct product of its group of units and a free group, so this particular version of splitting lemma is false.